# Eureka service discovery not working in Azure

Tags: spring, azure, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have 2 micro-services that register with Eureka. I run the projects locally and call one micro-service from another using Feign & Ribbon and everything works fine.

However when I deploy everything to Azure it no longer works.
I can see the services registered in eureka dashboard but when I click on a particular service I get an url like this http://100.79.xxxx.xx:xxxx and after loading for a while I get a connection timeout. Same happens in code when one micro-service calls the other through Eureka.

I also added this setting to eureka clients but it didn't help:

```
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address: false
```

It seems that the IP addresses of services instances are not reachable. 
Is there a way to make Eureka work on Azure? Thanks for your help.

Comment: spring cloud tries to guess the ip-address. If it can not (apparently on azure), you need to tell the eureka client what address to use.